# Can we call a stored procedure from another stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Can we call a stored procedure from another stored procedure?

Give me your samples.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you even **tried** this yourself?? Where are you stuck, what's the problem....

Comment: no i didn't...I have doubt that's it...

Comment: You should **try it** and if you have troubles or get error, **THEN** come here and ask ....

Comment: Atleast you have tried googled or read somthing on it

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow.. sry if i'm wrong ...

Comment: You should at least research the topic yourself (Google, Bing, MSDN Library) and try something yourself - **then** come and ask if you're stuck with something or don't get something to work. SO is not a site to teach the absolute basics - you can do that yourself. SO can help you figure out stuff that's beyond the basics of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can.

```
EXEC sp_theOther @Parameter1 = 120
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's better to use a user defined function instead, then you can call that inside stored procedures. This is assuming ofcoarse your using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
create procedure A as
    exec B

go

create procedure B as
   select 'I am B'
```

go